# Create calendar for an office 365 group

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, calendar, office-365-groups

I am using SharePoint Online (modern) from Office 365.
I have a publishing site.

I want to add a calendar web part, but there is no calendar for my SharePoint group:

"Something went wrong
We couldn't find a mailbox for this recipient. Either they don't have a mailbox or don't have a license assigned."

Is there a way to create such calendar, or some other solution for calendar sharing within team (we want to share holiday absences)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a standard traditional calendar with Add an app. It is called calendar. Said calendar can be synchronized with everyone's outlook.

Comment: It is a good solution, but I do not have this option, probably because I use modern version of SharePoint (similarily I don't have promoted links)

Comment: Is this because you have a 'communication site'? if this is the case, go into the settings, go to manage site features and turn on the line that says "team collaboration lists"

Comment: Yes, that was the problem and this addition helped. Thank you!